# change Bootstrap column/row order on mobile layout?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap is it possible to have these different layouts depending on the viewport? I've been searching about this and I'm aware of the concepts push, pull a i am also using the same but I have some different requirement and I am not able to think out how.

I have my bootstrap code code below as well as Expected and Actual output. I am not able to get the expected out put. Can someone help me with this.
[Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8qHb.png)
Expected
On Mobile  (Stacked)
C
A
D
B
E

On Desktop (CDE shoud be stacked)
A   B   C
        D
        E

Actual 
On Mobile (Stacked)
A
B
C
D
E
On Desktop (CDE)
A   B   C
        D
        E

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="well" id="first" style="background-color:red;">
        A - Image
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="well" id="second" style="background-color:pink">
        B - Thumb
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="heading">
        <h2 runat="server" class="product_title" id="productoverviewTitle"></h2>
        <p class="sub-heading">
          <div class="well" id="third" style="background-color:green">
            C
          </div>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="content">
        <div class="panel entry-content">
          <div class="well" id="fourth" style="background-color:orange">
            D
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="where-to-buy">
        <div class="well" style="background-color:lightblue">
          E
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Image is attached with this thread.

Comment: Have a look at Column Pulling/Pushing; can be used to change the order of columns based on layout size: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-column-ordering. Derp; I see you have `pull` and `push` there already. Now you need to use `col-*-pull` and `col-*-push` to change that depending on the layout; options are `xs`, `sm`, `md` and `lg`

Comment: Thank You Tim, I was able to figure out for first 2 but not able to figure out for next three as all are exist in sam ecolumn

Comment: Hmm yeah... I tried playing with it a bit, but I don't see a way to break them out of columns to re-arrange; you may need a separate base layout for different sizes to accomplish what you need. I'm not a CSS pro though, so maybe it's possible.

Comment: Thank You Tim, I am also not a css expert, but trying to solve this puzzle

Comment: @Vijay, is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Was able to accomplish using **flexbox** in Media Queries

It will be hard to rearrange nested columns.
Let's not say it's hard, it's not recommended.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #a {
    order: 4;
  }
  #b {
    order: 2;
  }
  #c {
    order: 1;
  }
  #d {
    order: 3;
  }
  #e {
    order: 5;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #d {
    bottom: 220px;
  }
  #e {
    bottom: 220px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-2" id="a">
      <div class="well" style="background-color:red; min-height:300px;">
        A - Image
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4" id="b">
      <div class="well" style="background-color:pink">
        B - Thumb
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6" id="c">
      <div class="heading">
        <h2 runat="server" class="product_title" id="productoverviewTitle"></h2>
        <p class="sub-heading">
          <div class="well" style="background-color:green">
            C
          </div>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6" id="d">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="panel entry-content">
          <div class="well" style="background-color:orange">
            D
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-6" id="e">
      <div class="where-to-buy">
        <div class="well" style="background-color:lightblue">
          E
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```